# Wiremock: Not able to set a stub based on finding a required parameter from a json body

Tags: java, json, api, wiremock

The title might look a little confusing. What I'm trying to do, in Mocklab, is create a stub, which would give me a certain response on the basis of a particular parameter or a set of parameter on the json body of that request.

Let's say the body of the request is like below:

```
{
 "A":{
     "B":{
         "key":"value",
          "key":"value" },
      "C":{
          "key":"value",
          "key":"value"
},
```

}

I want it to go through the entire body, and look for the key value pair in C, and give me a set response if it finds that pair. Rest of the body is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the information I'll describe is just taken from [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.petrikainulainen.net%2Fprogramming%2Ftesting%2Fwiremock-tutorial-request-matching-part-three%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGs6QkhmvVkW-l0zNqNNl7JkDyo5w).

I think you could do something like this:

```
givenThat(post(urlEqualTo("/foo")).withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.A.B.C.key", equalTo("value")))
```

If you needed to match on multiple key:value pairs, you can add additional `withRequestBody`s.

```
givenThat(post(urlEqualTo("/foo")).withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.A.B.C.key2", equalTo("value"))).withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.A.B.C.key2, equalTo("value")))
```

If your logic starts to get a little more tricky, I would suggest looking into creating a [custom matcher](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/)